# How to have only one processing file for multiple AJAX call

Tags: php, ajax

I wanted to know how we can have only one processing file for multiple ajax call. Files like delete.php and update.php

For example, if there are two tables, one for invoice and the other for stock, and In order to delete them through ajax, I would have to create two processing files (delete-invoice.php and delete-stock.php). How can I have just one processing file instead of creating multiple files

```
  // Ajax call to delete invoice 
  $('.delete_invoice').on('click',function(){
     var invoice_delete_id = $(this).data("invoicedelete");
     var element = this;
     $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/delete_invoice.inc.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {invoice_delete_id:invoice_delete_id},
        beforeSend: function(){
           $("#loadgif").show();  
        },
        complete: function(){
           $("#loadgif").hide();
        },
        success: function(delete_invoice_result){
           $(element).closest('tr').remove();
        }
     });
  }); 

  // Ajax call to delete stock
  $('.delete_stock').on('click',function(){
     var stock_delete_id = $(this).data("stockdelete");
     var element = this;
     $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/delete_stock.inc.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {stock_delete_id:stock_delete_id},
        beforeSend: function(){
           $("#loadgif").show();  
        },
        complete: function(){
           $("#loadgif").hide();
        },
        success: function(delete_stock_result){
           $(element).closest('tr').remove();
        }
     });
  });
```

How can I shorten this process? Hope you got an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. Thank you

Comment: In your PHP, just check if you got `$_POST['invoice_delete_id']` or `$_POST['stock_delete_id']` and you'll know what request it is and what should be done.

Comment: Ahan! This would work! Thank you :) @MagnusEriksson